# Cannot access property of an object in Yii 1.1 queryAll() result

Tags: php, object, yii

I have the following query:

```
$transactionIds = \Yii::app()->db->createCommand()                                                                                                                              
    ->select("transactionId")                                                                                                                                                   
    ->from("batch_lab_transactions")                                                                                                                                            
    ->where("batchId = :batchId", ["batchId" => $batch->id])                                                                                                                    
    ->queryAll();
```

Which is shown, according to `\Yii::log(json_encode($transactionIds));`:

> [{"transactionId":"658000024"},{"transactionId":"658000025"}]

I am trying to access `transactionId` key, but I keep receiving the error saying I am trying to access the non object. This is the loop I use:

```
foreach ($transactionIds as $transaction) {
    $transaction->transactionId // Error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get array of arrays with this code.

So you may use `$transaction['transactionId']`

The better way to use `queryColumn()` instead of `queryAll()` in this case:

```
$transactionIds = \Yii::app()->db->createCommand()                                                                                                                              
    ->select("transactionId")                                                                                                                                                   
    ->from("batch_lab_transactions")                                                                                                                                            
    ->where("batchId = :batchId", ["batchId" => $batch->id])                                                                                                                    
    ->queryColumn(); // <-- change here

foreach ($transactionIds as $transactionId) {
    echo $transactionId;
}
```